# Can't download heroku on ubuntu for windows (wls)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I type the command to download the cli, `sudo snap install --classic heroku` this message appears:

> `error: cannot communicate with server: Post
>   http://localhost/v2/snaps/heroku: dial unix /run/snapd.socket:
>   connect: no such file or directory`

And when I use this other link:

> `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | shcurl
>   https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

And then I type `heroku create`, this other message pops out:

> `heroku: command not found`

Comment: What happens when you type `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` usually it will ask for superuser password and then just install. Have you seen the console return a bunch of text ?

Comment: W: GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details

Comment: I am not too sure. This may be an error you will have with Ubuntu as well; but running Ubuntu inside Windows may expose you to errors you wouldn't have with a real Ubuntu partition... Try to google this very error

Answer (score 5):

It seems that snaps are missing on Ubuntu for Windows. However, I was able to install Heroku on the WSL through Node Package Manager. Try `$ npm install -g heroku`.